# ng-model not getting updated in radio button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my code, the radio button gets checked `onload` but the `ng-model` value `session.payment` is not updated. I have to select it again to `update`.

```
<li ng-repeat="method in data">
    <label>
        <input ng-model="session.payment" ng-checked="method.active === 'ACTIVE'"
               type="radio" value="{{method.paymentId}}">
        <span class="radio-btn"></span> 
    </label>
</li>
```

Comment: *"the radio button gets checked onload"* - how exactly do you do it?

Comment: [ngChecked docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) state that "this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior".

Comment: how are you loading the session.payment in your controller. paste your controller code as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use ng-checked alongside ng-model. Rather than setting the ng-checked directive onLoad, just set the session.payment variable in your controller.

So now you should have your HTML as:

```
<input ng-model="session.payment" type="radio" value="{{method.paymentId}}">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.session.payment = method.active === 'ACTIVE';
```

Comment: session.payment variable in your javascript.... i did not understand this..

Comment: i hope he meant in the controller of angular which is binding your view containing checkbox

Comment: yes, that is what I meant. Updated answer for clarity.

Comment: you're checking the radio button according to the condition method.active === 'ACTIVE' correct? And you want that value to be bound to the session.payment variable in the controller, which is what the ng-model directive is doing.  As the value changes in the controller, the radio button will be updated accordingly.  I updated my answer with a little more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually session.payment by default is false.. when i select the radio button its value changes to 9876... number...

Comment: I'm really not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish.